# Alias in Where clauses and Join on clauses

Tags: sql, join, where-clause, alias

I thought using an alias in the WHERE clause and JOIN ON clause is illegal because of the logical execution sequence. These two clauses are before the SELECT so the alias is not defined.

However, I read two codes lately they had an alias in these two clauses and they ran without problems.

```
SELECT w1.id
FROM weather AS w1
JOIN weather AS w2 ON DATEDIFF(w1.recordDate, w2.recordDate) = 1
                   AND w1.Temperature > w2.Temperature;
```

This is on leetcode, using an alias in the JOIN clause.

```
SELECT o.OrderID, o.OrderDate, c.CustomerName
FROM Customers AS c, Orders AS o
WHERE c.CustomerName = 'Around the Horn' 
  AND c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID;
```

This is on W3school, using an alias in the Where clause.

Now, I am confused about the restrictions of using an alias. Any thoughts?

Comment: Neither of these is uses aliases.  They are all using qualified column references.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing *column* aliases and *table* aliases.

Table aliases are defined in the `FROM` clause.  As a best practice, they should always be used to reference to column names.  In your first example, `w1` and `w2` are *table* aliases and `w1.temperature` and `w2.temperature` are *qualified column references*.

A *column* alias is defined in the `SELECT` clause:

```
select 'this is a ' as column_alias
```

The `column_alias` cannot be used in the `ON` or `WHERE` clauses associated with the `SELECT`.

Comment: So basically if it's a table alias in FROM, it's compatible with All Clauses including (WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING, ORDER BY, JOIN ) since FROM is at first in the execution sequence.

Comment: @NomardicRoku . . . Basically yes.  The only tweak is that `FROM` is first for *parsing* the query.  What gets executed is an optimized directed acyclic graph that bears little resemblance to the original query.